# Filtering JSON response from ECDC server

Tags: json, api

I'm working on a small project, which needs to access the ECDC API and decode the response JSON data. The content is simply COVID-19 statistics for subnational regions in Europe.

However, the source I have found sends the information of **all European countries** together, which makes it about 4.7 MB of data, which is far too much for a simple website and I need the data of **just one of those countries**. I have tried looking for other databases/APIs, yet none of them even have this info, let alone have the ability to filter it (especially for my country).

Here is the link to the API:
https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/subnationalcaseweekly/json/

Of course I have also tried filtering via the URL, which is usually the case for these types of queries.
If we take Germany for example:
https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/subnationalcaseweekly/json&country=Germany
but the response results in an error.

If anyone succeeds in filtering the response result by country, so there wouldn't be so much unnecessary data, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: There are a couple of things to note.  First, the data you are downloading is not being maintained as of December 2020. It appears that they have moved to a weekly distribution of data. I suppose if you do not need up-to-date data then you should be okay. Second, it does not appear that the authors of the API have provided a means of filtering the data on the server side. So, I did a quick search for "online proxy to filter json data" and came up with this: https://blog.api.rakuten.net/top-proxy-apis/. What language/tool are you using to retrieve the data?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Firstly, I don't know what you mean by "not being maintained" as the link I provided includes measurements up to the 17th week of 2021, which is fairly recent. I'm using JavaScript for retrieving the data, so that is not problem. I have switched to a proxy API as you have suggested and it is working as intended, so thank you for the suggestion.